# Gradle: Force another Operating System

Tags: java, gradle, build

I use `OperatingSystem.current()` for my daily work with gradle. Now, I want to assemble my java project for different platforms, so I change manually my build.gradle files to build for a specific OS.

My question: Is there a way to specify the OS to use (returned by OperatingSystem.current()) directly in the gradle command line? If no, what is the best strategy to do cross building ?

Note: I depend on some libraries that use themselves the `OperatingSystem.current()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm cringing while writing this, it's wrong on so many levels - I suggest you'll avoid forcing Gradle to think it's in a different OS.
But assuming you can't avoid it ->

I all depends on the version of Gradle you're using, I'd assume you're using the latest version (in older version that might be simpler)

`OperatingSystem.current()` works with the `"os.name"` environment variable which you **can** override very simply with a -D flag on the Gradle command.

BUT, and this is a big but, Gradle is not the problem here. The underlying JRE being used to execute the build contains OS specific code - see UNIXProcess on UNIX systems.
The current implementation of UNIXProcess blocks overriding the `"os.name"` value as it performs validations on it.
It's possible you'de be able to bypass that by creating a class in `org.gradle.internal.os` package that exposes the package-private `OperatingSystem.resetCurrent()` method and then force `OperatingSystem.current()` to re-evaluate, bypassing any **real** JRE checks.

Something like so:

```
print OperatingSystem.current()
System.setProperty("os.name", <some other OS>)
OperatingSystemWrapper.resetCurrent()
print OperatingSystem.current()
```

---

After some additional conversation over the comments, now I understand that the real requirement here is to take conditional dependency on native libs in a simple way that will allow the OP to remove dependency on `OperatingSyste.current()`

Taking a sample

```
apply plugin: "java"

dependencies {
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl:3.2.0"
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-platform:3.2.0:natives-windows"
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-platform:3.2.0:natives-linux"
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-platform:3.2.0:natives-osx"
}
```

One can add conditional dependency via a "-P" flag (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties)

```
apply plugin: "java"

dependencies {
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl:3.2.0"
    if (buildos == "windows") {
       compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-platform:3.2.0:natives-windows"
    } else if (buildos == "linux") {
       compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-platform:3.2.0:natives-linux"
    } else if (buildos == "osx") {
       compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-platform:3.2.0:natives-osx"
    }
}



gradle build -Pbuildos=windows
```

A similar thing can be done with a "-D" flag, but then you need to access it with `System.getProperty`

One can take it even further by building custom tasks and configurations (inheriting from compile/implementation) for each flavor instead of relying on -P flags

Comment: So this is a terrible practice. Is there any proper way to do "cross" build (assemble different distributions on the same computer) with gradle? I guess using VM would be the best strategy?

Comment: Well, cross compiling is one thing and fooling your build tool to think it's in a different OS is something else.
Take Golang for example, it support cross compiling natively via the GOOS and GOARCH vars - no need to fool anything and anyone.
It's only a question of what you're trying to do and what are you using that takes direct dependency on OperatingSystem.current().  
Java is, by nature, cross platform. Unless you're using some specific calls using JNI or have other dependencies hardcoded into your application - more details would help

Comment: Yeah, I agree that fooling the build tool is bad. Let's forget that.
I use LWJGL, an OpenGL binding that drive native libraries. So there are specific jar containing native libs for specific os. 
Building for another platform is "trivial", I just need to ask to Gradle "for this build, you should use the windows jar; and for the next build, let's use linux jars". 

For now, it still a manual operation of myself, so my question, is how to do that correctly, and automatically. Maybe I should open a new thread?

Comment: So let me get this straight, as you're not providing a lot of information still. You have something like this in you build code
dependencies {
 compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl:${lwjglVersion}"
 compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-platform:${lwjglVersion}:natives-windows"
 compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-platform:${lwjglVersion}:natives-linux"
 compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-platform:${lwjglVersion}:natives-osx"
}
     And you want to include the right native lib for the right os-specific-jar right?

Comment: Sorry for my lack of informations. Yep, you understood perfectly. Since there are multiple natives (vulkan, OpenAL, Joml... and more), I prefer to make one lightweight build per platform.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Indeed, this solution is simple and feet to my needs.